# warning: discards 'const' qualifiers from pointer target type

Tags: c

Doesn't  `const char *s`  means that "s is a pointer which is pointing towards a constant char " then why it is giving me this warning? I am not trying to change values.

In first function warning is `return discards 'const' qualifiers from pointer target type`.

and in second warning is `assignment discards 'const' qualifiers from pointer target type`.

I  was trying to make library functions which are defined in `string.h`,  and also tell me how to correct it.

```
char *my_strchr( const char *s, int c )
{
    for(;*s!='\0';s++)
       if(*s==c)
          return s; // warning

    return 0;
}



char *my_strpbrk( const char *s1, const char *s2 )
{
    char *s2ptr;

    for(;*s1!='\0';s1++)
        for(s2ptr=s2;*s2ptr!='\0';s2ptr++) //warning
           if(*s1==*s2ptr)
               return s2ptr;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your `return` statement is converting `const char *` to `char *`, i.e., it's implicitly changing the type by discarding the `const` restriction.  You can fix it by changing the function return type to `const char *` (or `char const *`), or removing `const` from the argument type, or you can circumvent the type system by inserting an explicit cast, i.e. `return (char *)s;`

Comment: Sidenote: Return value of `strpbrk` should be pointer from string `s1`, not `s2`.

Comment: "const char *s means that "s is a pointer which is pointing towards a constant char " --> No.  `s` points to `char` that should not be modified.  The data `s` points to may or may not be constant, but this function shall not attempt to change it.  Look. but don't touch.

Comment: @Ummair ..If any of the answers below has solved your problem, do mark any one as accepted. Read more about this here: [stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

> Doesn't const char *s means that "s is a pointer which is pointing towards a constant char"

Indeed it does. You get the warning because you are trying to convert this into a pointer pointing to a (non-constant) char. There is a rule in C saying that it is always ok to convert from pointer-to-type into pointer-to-const-type, *but not the other way around*.

It doesn't matter if your code tries to change the values or not. Just by using `char*` you tell the compiler that you want a pointer which is allowed to change values.

Most of the C standard library functions do not always make sense when it comes to "const correctness". There is for example no way to cleanly implement `strchr`. You will have to return `(char*)s` and cast away the `const`, which is very bad programming practice. This is the fault of the person who specified the `strchr` function: it is flawed by design.

Comment: Generally, there was not much thought put into the design of the C standard library. They just took a bunch of commonly used 1970s Unix functions of diverse quality and decided "these are standard". So please don't go look at the C standard lib for advise how to write functions. Some functions there are canonical (like memcpy), while some are complete nonsense and blatantly dangerous to use (gets, printf/scanf family, strncpy etc).

Comment: Yeah, some of them are seriously bad (and inconsistent), like `gets()`.

Comment: It has only take 22 years to get rid of `gets()`  (C89-C11).

Comment: You're using constant in place of const, those are different concepts.

Comment: @2501 Yes, but that is a pointless detail in this context, this is an attempt to pedagogically try to explain basics to beginners. If you already know about the various C rules for conversions between pointer to type and pointer to qualified type, which I suspect you do, there is actually no need for you to read this answer in the first place; you'll learn nothing new from it.

Comment: But beginners don't, so they will be confused when they later learn const != constant, which you taught them that it is the same.

Comment: When used as a formal parameter (in a function parameter list), it means "a pointer to a char that the function promises not to change" regardless of whether it is actually a constant.

Answer (score 8):

> For first warning: *return discards 'const' qualifiers from pointer target type*

C does not have an implicit conversion from `const-qualified` pointer types to non-const-qualified ones, so to overcome the warning you need to add it explicitly.

Replace **`return s;`** with **`return (char *)s;`**

> For second warning: *assignment discards 'const' qualifiers from pointer target type*

- **'s2ptr'** is of type **`char *`** and **'s2'** is of type **`const char *`**
- You are not allowed to assign a **`const char*`** value to a **`char *`** pointer.

And regarding how to fix this warning... It depends on what you are trying to do. Either you can make `char *s2ptr` as `const char * s2ptr` or remove the `const` from `s2`.

So if you wish to convert `char *s2ptr` to `const char *s2ptr`, do remember to explicitly cast `s2ptr` to `(char *)s2ptr` while returning it in the *my_strpbrk()* function.

Comment: "You are not allowed to assign a const char* value to a char * pointer." - Why?

Comment: @AkshayImmanuelD: because that would allow subsequent code to modify the pointed to string, which controverts the intention of `const`.

Answer (score -2):

For the first case, your return type is a `char` You are trying to pass a `const char` as the return.

For the second case, the problem is in `s2ptr=s2`.  `s2ptr` is a `char` and `s2` is a `const char`.

Comment: In first case my return type is `char *` I think it returns an address which POINTS to a character. In second `s2ptr` and `s2` are both pointers I am just giving the address which is in `s2` to `s2ptr`, isn't that allowed? If not how to correct it.