# strptime throws Segmentation fault when passing char array to const char *

Tags: c

I am getting segmentation fault when I try to pass char array to const char *

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

static char *
get_valid_date_format(const char *date) {
    struct tm result;
    char *ret;
    char **f;
    
    char *formats[] = {"%Y", "%Y-%m", "%y-%m", "%Y-%m-%d", "%y-%m-%d",
        "%Y%m%d", "%y%m%d", "%Y-%m-%d %T", "%y-%m-%d %T", "%Y%m%d%H%M%S",
        "%y%m%d%H%M%S", "%Y-%m-%dT%T", "%y-%m-%dT%T", "%Y-%m-%dT%TZ",
        "%y-%m-%dT%TZ", "%Y-%m-%d %TZ", "%y-%m-%d %TZ", "%Y%m%dT%TZ",
        "%y%m%dT%TZ", "%Y%m%d %TZ", "%y%m%d %TZ", NULL };
        
    
    memset(&result, 0, sizeof(result));
    for (f = formats; f && *f; f++)
    {
        printf("check format: %s\n", *f);
        ret = strptime(date, *f, &result);
        if (ret && *ret == '\0')
        {
            printf("found Format: %s\n\n", *f);
            return *f;
        }
    }

    return (char *)0;
}


void main()
{
    char *format;
    char *date = "2020-07-25T00:10:58";
    char date2[] = "2020-07-25T00:10:58";
    char *date3 = "2020-07-25T00:10:58.000Z";
    
    date2[3] = '1';

    format = get_valid_date_format(date2);
    if (format == NULL) {
        printf("format is NULL\n");
        return;
    } else {
        printf("format found = %s\n", format);
    }
}
```

If I call get_valid_date_format(date), then it works fine.  So calling with char * works find but when passing char[] then I get segmentation fault.  I need to use array as I need to modify it before calling get_valid_date_format.

Comment: formats[] is not used outside get_valid_date_format().  In the main, I actually don't need to know the actual format but just whether the format is valid or not.  The code works as I have it if I call  get_valid_date_format(date) but not when I call get_valid_date_format(date2).  When I pass an array date2[] instead of pointer *date, then I get segmentation fault at strptime() function call.  I think the problem is trying to figure out how to pass the array date2[] to get_valid_date_format, so that strptime() is happy.

Comment: Where are your `#include`s?

Comment: @M.NejatAydin  updated the code with the #include s

Comment: Write in the first line: `#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 700` and google for `The _XOPEN_SOURCE Feature Test Macro`.

Comment: Did you read your compiler warnings?

Comment: I had to use two `#define` statements, as in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/15334600/11831920

Comment: What compiler and system are you using? What compiler flags are you using?

I ran this program on macOS X 10.14 with Clang v.11.0.0 without any problem (well, I had to change your bad definition of main(), remove the unecessary return; and make formats static).

Comment: @M.NejatAydin  adding #define _XOPEN_SOURCE  seems to have taken care of the segmentation fault.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [M. Nejat Aydin commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62785456/strptime-throws-segmentation-fault-when-passing-char-array-to-const-char/62785991#comment111030017_62785456), `strptime` is not a standard C function, it comes from BSD and is [part of the POSIX standard](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strptime.html) used by Unix. To ensure it is loaded, add `-D_XOPEN_SOURCE=700` to load X/Open and POSIX extensions.

---

Compiler warnings will tell you about a host of other potential issues. If you're using a command line compiler like gcc or clang, you have to run compiler warnings on. There's a host of options, I recommend `-Wall -Wshadow -Wwrite-strings -Wextra -Wconversion -std=c11 -pedantic`.

`char *formats[]` declares an array of `char *` local to the function. You're returning one of those elements. Normally returning a local variable can cause a memory fault because that memory can be deallocated when the function exits. But `formats` consists of string literals which are not deallocated. But you've incorrectly declared them writable `char *`. [You can go from non-const to const, but you can't go from const to non-const](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37160873/warning-discards-const-qualifiers-from-pointer-target-type).

`formats` should be `const char *formats[]`, an array of read-only `const char *`. They are read-only [string literals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2589949/string-literals-where-do-they-go) which are never deallocated (static) and can be safely returned from the function. For belt-and-suspenders, declare `formats` [`static`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_variable#Static_local_variables) because it only needs ever to be allocated once.

Similarly, `get_valid_date_format` should return `static const char *`, `format` should be `const char *`, and `f` is a `const char **`.

Though some compilers will allow `void main`, that is not valid. [`main` returns an `int`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entry_point#C_and_C++).

`char *foo = "...";` is incorrect. It is a `char foo[] = "..."` or a `const char *foo` if it's read-only. This applies to all your date variables. `const char *date = ...`, `const char *date3 = "..."` and because you modify `date2`, `char date2[] = ...`.

There is no need to check if `f` is true in the loop, just `*f`, but it doesn't hurt.

`return (char *)0;` is better written as `return NULL;`

There is no need to initialize `result` with `memset` since you're just passing it to `strptime` which will overwrite with its own values.

Comment: By declaring the function `static char * get_valid_date_format` you are telling the compiler that the function `get_valid_data_format` may not be called from outside the compilation unit. It does NOT return a static pointer. Instead, declare `static char* formats[] = `

Comment: @JeffSzuhay Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: No, there is no problem with `formats`. The returned value is a pointer to the first character of a `string literal` and `string literals` have `static storage duration`.

Comment: @M.NejatAydin Are you sure? `test.c:13:24: warning: initializing 'char *' with an expression of type 'const char [11]' discards qualifiers [-Wincompatible-pointer-types-discards-qualifiers]`

Comment: Are you using c++ compiler?

Comment: @M.NejatAydin No, clang in C11 mode. `clang -Wall -Wshadow -Wwrite-strings -Wextra -Wconversion -std=c11 -pedantic -g`

Comment: @Schwern  Thanks for these suggestions.  Adding #define _XOPEN_SOURCE fixed the segmentation issue but these are good suggestions that I will take into account.

Comment: `-Wwrite-strings` flag gives the same warning with the line `char *date = "2020-07-25T00:10:58";` as well. There is no problem with the declaration. Attempting to modify a sting literal is a problem, but this is not the case here. The problem with the code is that the compiler doesn't see the declaration of `strptime` function unless _XOPEN_SOURCE is `#define`d. See my comment to the original question.

Comment: @M.NejatAydin Ahh. You should write that as an answer.

Comment: I am too lazy right now :) And this is a Posix question rather than C. strptime is a Posix function.